# Holding a data structure to keep track of classes in configuration file

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a C# application which uses an XML file for configuration.
The configuration file is used for determining if a class is relevant for the current running of the application.

The application monitors several specs of a localhost, each parameter that the application monitors is represented by a class in the project.

What is the correct way to keep track of which classes to monitor and which not?
I'm currently holding a dictionary of the following kind:

```
Dictionary<string, bool>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for here is some kind of provider implementation where you want to configure the set of classes which should be created at run time. I don't think there is one correct way to do this. The correct choice would depend largely on the details of your exact use case.

I would go about this by putting together a factory for each type of class you want to create ([see factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)). You can then configure which factories should be loaded up at runtime using your xml configuration file. You will need to stipulate the assembly and type in the file so you can create the type at run time using reflection. This can be done using the [Activator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx) class in C#.

A better approach might be to make use of a dependency injection framework which will do most of the difficult reflection work for you. I am a fan of [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) but there are plenty of others out there. If you want to stick to purely .net take a look at the [Unity Container](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33090/Using-the-Dependency-Injection-Pattern-and-Unity-C).

Comment: My problem is that i don't want all classes on my assembly to be on the configuration file.
Any way that i can specify more which of them i want to be on the configuration file?